# Get value of posted json data with Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

When I make an ajax call, I get the ID of my input and I add the id to my json data.

I need to get this id to use it id my success function.

IE : In data id = 1, i need in success to get .qte1

If you have any idea... :)

```
$('#action-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_qty.php',
        data: {
            'id': $('input[name=qte]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".qte").html("");
            $(".qte").append(data);

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the json you are passing in success function?

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/baptcottey/eb6aa48346996d7917a9abfb48e68a27/raw/0676ed0ad39a0e7a2bf918adc648dc836da2a5ab/gistfile1.txt#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can just concat the value as such

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
var $div = "#qte" + data.id;
$($div).html("test");
```

I have converted to `json` object because if you don't have access to the `php` file this at least converts from string to object. Make sure you are using a `#`to call a specific `div` not a class.

This is my PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$arr = array("id"=> $_POST['id'],"qty"=> "1");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Add a console.log(data) to the js to check if data is populated.

Comment: {"id":"9","qty":"-8"}

Comment: What do you get when you console.log($div); ?

Comment: {"id":"9","qty":"-8"}
js.js:15 #qteundefined

Comment: So data.id is not set. try data['id']

Comment: {"id":"9","qty":"-8"}
js.js:15 #qteundefined

Find my js here : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/baptcottey/b1f290e65a4ab66cb98d0eb25a46bc05/raw/fd1c25a1e010109d55dd25cec2bae51fc19a07ce/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Sorry not tried, i can't edit the php file, i juste get the json result..

Comment: But the ID i post is still equal to The ID i get, so it's not a problem with the value Of The ID

Comment: @Baptiste I have added another line of code please try to convert the result from string to json object.

Comment: Yeaaaaaah !
Working ! I've juste change data.id to data.qty to get the quantity ! Thank u very much :D